# Secure networking for video surveillance system

Tags: networking, router, security, ethernet

I'm configuring a video surveillance system for residential use using a windows 10 workstation as server and 6 or so cameras, and am looking to configure it in a way that is secure from hacking. My questions boils down to: 1) is using a managed PoE switch a good option given my use-case or is there is a simpler solution? 2) Is the premise correct that I should sequester ip camera traffic to its own network or is it secure to connect this through the internet router which is set up with 2-factor authentication?

Additional context: Based on research into securing a video surveillance system, the recommendation was to have all data from ip camera traffic on its own network. Initially, I attempted to connect an unmanaged network switch (with PoE) directly into one of two ethernet ports on the server (with the other ethernet port connected to the internet router). But this didn't work and the cameras were only recognized on the windows server after connecting the switch to the router's LAN port.

A resource suggested that using a managed switch with the same connectivity I indicated above (going into one of the ethernet ports) would work properly. But as a non-expert, I am concerned that going with a managed switch will add complexity and require a lot of additional configuration. Is this option the best given my use case or are there simpler approaches?

Notes on the hardware: the unmanaged switch I started with: https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/unmanaged-switch/tl-sl1311mp/. The managed switch I'm considering: https://www.tp-link.com/us/business-networking/easy-smart-switch/tl-sg1210mpe/.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because designing security solutions for a whole network is not the kind of question that fits SuperUser's Q&A format. SuperUser questions need to be the kind that have clear answers.

Comment: When you find another forum to ask this question in, be sure to specify what your threat model is. That is, what kinds of attacks are you hoping to protect against?

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and if this question is too general for this type of forum, feel free to close it (or I can). In terms of the types of attacks I'd like to prevent, this comes down to preventing any attempt to change configuration or functioning of the system by some outside party since I'm the only one who should should have access. What that means specifically ("DNS hacking" or what not) I don't have sufficient knowledge to say.